# develop a method which receives 1D array then i want to return a 2D array after run function to each element of the receiving array.

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am going to develop a method which receives 1D array then i want to return a 2D array after run function to each element of the receiving array.

I need to enter an array to be an element of the returned array but I do not know how can i do that. i have problem in this line. 
Any suggestion please to fix this issue.

```
           ArrayAfterFill[1][i]= ArrayAfterFill[1][temp];
```

this is my code

```
int[][] Fill (int Array[]){

    int ArrayAfterFill [][] = new int[2][24];
    int[] temp = new int [2];
    for (int i =0; i< Array.length;i++){
        temp = Fill(i);
        ArrayAfterFill[1][i]= ArrayAfterFill[1][temp];



    }

    return ArrayofSasortedActionArrayBease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch error. You can't use an array as an index of an array (which is the problem on your error line). `temp` is not an `int`, it is an array.

Comment: I want to receive it as  int [ ]  ? I know about this and i want to fix it

Comment: Aderis thank you , but you have not answered my question . Just you say what i have written in my question

Comment: What do you mean by receive, and what is "it"? I do not know exactly what you are trying to achieve, and so I cannot provide a correct solution, only point out where and what your problems are.

Comment: Thank you  Aderis , i want  the return array of this function to be like this    int [ ] [ ] = { int [ ], int { }, ... etc}

Comment: I understand the return type, as that was specified in your function definition. What I do not understand is what values you want in that two dimensional array, and how you are going about getting those values. All of the type mismatch errors make it hard to figure out what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to make the function return an array where every index is an instance of the parameter array? For example `{parameterArray, parameterArray, parameterArray...}`.

Comment: I just now realized that you had the `Fill()` method overloaded to be `int[][] Fill(int[] Array)` and `int[] Fill(int value)`, which is why you weren't getting errors on previous lines. I edited my answer to account for that.